# Custom symbols not showing up in Symbol Selector of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, legend

How do you get Petroleum symbols into the Map legend box (not the content table) instead of the standard "circle or square"?  I am looking to use the Unkown (black symbol) and Active / Producing symbols (Red symbol). However when I click on the sybol to open up the property layer box, it only shows the basic symbols, even when you click to add Petroleum.

Please see the inserted image.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the symbols you mention - can you include some graphics/links?

Comment: Added and custom symbology do not show up in the symbol selector until after you save, close and re-open the mxd.

Comment: I added the image of what I am referring too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for creating and using new symbols is described in the help page entitled [About creating new symbols](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000004000000), in particular within the section entitled Creating new symbols in Style Manager where it says:

> While it is convenient to create symbols as you need them when
>   authoring your maps, sometimes it is more efficient to build a whole
>   style of symbols all at once before you begin. This is especially true
>   if you are building a set of symbols to meet specific characteristics
>   defined in a map specification. In this case, you can build symbols
>   directly into a style from the Style Manager dialog box. They will be
>   ready to search and use when you begin authoring your map.

Comment: I went and did the INSERT LEGEND then conversion, ungroup etc.. I got it.  Thank you.